# Trying to catch a exception from another function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created 2 dataframes and written a function to concat it and forced a nameerror by giving incorrect dataframes to concat and want to catch that exception in another function as shown below. But could not do that. Any Help is appreciated.

```
di1 = {'name':'xxxx', 'phone-no':'685985'}
di2 = {'name':'yyyy', 'phone-no':'9907868'}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(di1,index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(di2,index=[0])


def conc(df1,df2):
    df_conc=pd.concat([df1,df])
    return df_conc

#print(conc(df1,df2))
    
def tryit(func):
    try:
        return func
    except:
        pass
        return False
    

print(tryit(conc(df1,df2)))
```

Comment: You had a typo. It's fixed now.

Comment: Your 'pass' statement means the 'return False' will never be reached

Comment: He actually didn't have a typo, I submitted the same edit, it's there on purpose

Comment: `pass` does nothing there... but try `except Exception as e:` `return e`

Comment: Mainly its not even coming to except: clause.

Comment: Basically i want to catch a exception in first function with another function so that i don't have to touch the first function.

Comment: This question is not very clear, to me at least. What do you mean "forcing the error"? If you mean to  something like `print(tryit(conc(non_existing_1, non_existing_2)))` then this will never work. The `NameError` is raised before either `conc` or `tryit` are even called

Comment: Hello, I want to break the loop at certain statement. But was not able to  status = 0
count = 0
while status==0:
    if count <= 5:
        count += 1
        print('first function') ## status == 0
        print('second function') ## status == 0
        print('third function') ## returned status = 1
        status = 1 ## I want to break the loop here without using condition for each statement
        print('fourth function')
        print('fifth function')
    else:
        break    I want the loop to stop at 3rd function where the status is changed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is you're calling the conc function and passing its return value in to the tryit function, instead of calling the conc function inside the tryit function. It should look like:

```
def tryit(func, val1, val2):
    try:
        return func(val1, val2)
    except NameError:
        return False

print(tryit(conc, df1, df2)
```

but as Chris mentioned it would be easier to catch it in the original function

Comment: What if `func` might return `False`? How will this differentiate between `False` returned by `func`, and `False` returned by `tryit` due to `NameError`?

Comment: If you want to be able to do that, you'd have to return something unique that func would never return. Returning None would be another option, or some string if you just want to report that func had an error. It really depends what you want to happen in the event of an error

Comment: Well, it kind of was a rhetorical question. The cleanest solution here would be to simply re-raise the exception, making `tryit` unnecessary. Or, maybe, pass the sentinel value to `tryit`, so at least it is flexible.

Comment: Agreed; sorry, didn't realise it wasn't the OP commenting. I can't think of a reason to do things this way, but I've had valid reasons to want to do other obscure things before, hence I answered the question the OP asked

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it did not work is because you are passing the result of `conc(df1, df2)` to the `tryit` function.  So the error occurs before `tryit` is called.

To avoid this, you need to run `conc` function inside the `tryit`, and for that, you need to pass the arguments `df1`, `df2` along.
Anonymous arguments `*args` and `**kwargs` allow you to define `tryit` as a generic function.

If you do not want to pass arguments along, there is an option to define another function without arguments, and pass that to `tryit`.

```py
import pandas as pd

di1 = {'name':'xxxx', 'phone-no':'685985'}
di2 = {'name':'yyyy', 'phone-no':'9907868'}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(di1,index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(di2,index=[0])


def conc(df1,df2):
    df_conc=pd.concat([df1,df])
    return df_conc

def tryit(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Following error occurred:")
        print(e)
        return e

def _conc():
    # if passing arguments along is a problem,
    # define an inner function that executes the 
    # procedure without argument
    return conc(df1, df2)


tryit(conc, df1, df2)
tryit(_conc)
```

Result:

```py
Following error occurred:
name 'df' is not defined
Following error occurred:
name 'df' is not defined
```

Comment: This Helped a lot for most of the scenarios Thanks! . If I face anything i will post it.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to handle this is probably to return an error if the exception is thrown in the first function, since you're basically returning that same value in the second function.

```
di1 = {'name':'xxxx', 'phone-no':'685985'}
di2 = {'name':'yyyy', 'phone-no':'9907868'}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(di1,index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(di2,index=[0])


def conc(df1,df2):
    try:
        df_conc=pd.concat([df1,df])
        return df_conc
    except NameError:
        return 'Invalid df names'
        

#print(conc(df1,df2))
    
def tryit(func):
    try:
        return func
    except:
        pass
        return False
    

print(tryit(conc(df1,df2)))
```

Comment: Is there any other way. So i don't have touch the first function

Comment: I agree, and bypass the `tryit` call: `print(conc(df1, df2))`

Comment: Or, keep it if there are many such functions... but this all seems unnecessary, normal error raising should be preferred as it gives plenty of information

Answer (score -1):

```
di1 = {'name':'xxxx', 'phone-no':'685985'}
di2 = {'name':'yyyy', 'phone-no':'9907868'}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(di1,index=[0])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(di2,index=[0])

def conc(df1,df2):
    df_conc=pd.concat([df1,df2])
    return df_conc

def tryit(func):
    try:
        return func
    except Exception as e:
        return e


print(tryit(conc(df1,df2)))
```